# Why is my SSH session so slow when Dropbox is uploading?

Tags: ssh, dropbox

When Dropbox is uploading, my SSH session to a remote server (a DigitalOcean droplet) is extremely slow. By slow, I mean the latency is very high: I type a word and it appears in the terminal 5+ seconds later, one letter at a time.

I have the Dropbox client's upload rate set to "limit automatically".

Other applications, e.g. general web browsing, seem unaffected.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You IP provider limits upload/download speed and transferring files / sync is taking up the majority of your bandwidth.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: While I've no doubt that I'm hitting a limit somewhere, I think there must be more to it than that. SSH packets are tiny, other applications (which transfer much more data) are unaffected, and shouldn't there be some kind of load balancing in the OS that prevents one application from completely dominating network resources?

Comment: I have same problem without dropbox or any other application taking much bandwidth. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @ruuter: The problem went away when I upgraded to fibre broadband. Seems the extra headroom helped. Don't think it solved the root cause.