# Why is my ssh connection so slow?

Tags: networking, ssh

There has been similar [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527202/why-is-my-ssh-session-so-slow-when-dropbox-is-uploading) been asked time ago, but has no answers. I noticed today that my connection with ssh to other computer on local network it was very slow. When typing in terminal the letters would show few seconds later. I do not know if it is important, but I was downloading with qBitTottent at the same time, but there is more than enough bandwidth (torrent took ~100KBib/s). I tried again and I noticed that it works OK for ~1 minut and than it became slower and slower.

Than I switched computers and I started to transfer big file (4 GB) to the first computer with `scp` command. The transfer speed at the begining was more than 1 MB/s but in less than a minute slowly fell to 0.

What is wrong?

- I am connecting through WiFi (both laptops).
- Both computers have Ubuntu 14.04 installed.
- On both computers was running qBitTorrent, but this should not make
  any difference as there is enough bandwidth.
- First computer:

  `02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
  03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)`
- Second computer:

  `02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev 35)
  00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 05)`

Comment: Not enough information to debug the issue. What is your connection type? DSL? Fiber? What's the download and upload speed? Have you setup any kind of bandwidth limit on qbittorrent?

Comment: Fire up the wireshark on both, filter the port 22, watch if it simultaneous when you use ssh.